# $75$ students in three balanced groups: Probability, cardinality.

Tags: calculus, probability

**EDIT: more consistent attempt.**

Let say we have $n=75$ students, divided into 3 groups.

> What is the probability that the three groups are balanced and the probability that $Marc$ and $Gato$ are in the same group?

Let $\Omega=\{(m_1,m_2,m_3)\in\{0,\cdots,75\}^3: m_1+m_2+m_3=75\}$

Let $\omega_1\in\Omega : \omega_1=(m_1,m_2,m_3)$ representes the number of studies in each group. *Question:* How can I compute card$(\Omega)$?

Another approach:

$\Omega_2=\{(E_1,E_2,E_3), E_i\in \Gamma : E_1\cup E_2\cup E_3, \quad E_i\cap Ej=\emptyset \}$

$$\text{Card}(\Omega_2)=\sum_{k_1+k_2+k_3=75}\dbinom{75}{k_1}\dbinom{75-k_1}{k_2}\dbinom{75-k_1-k_2}{k_3}=3^{75}.$$

How can I continue?

Comment: Just to clarify, by balanced you mean each group has 25 members right?

Comment: @MarcGato- it's fine I'm just a little under the weather today so I need to double check everything to be sure.

Comment: Can a group have $0$ students?

Comment: @barakmanos yes, you can look at my attempt I choose $m_1,m_2,m_3\in \{0,\cdots,75\}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OP do not specify very clearly how the groups are decided, I suppose here
that each student chooses randomly one of the three groups with equiprobability.
The natural model is then $\Omega=G^S=\lbrace f : S\to G \rbrace$ where
$G=\lbrace G_1,G_2,G_3 \rbrace$ is the set of groups and
$S=\lbrace S_1,S_2,\ldots, S_{75} \rbrace$ is the set of all students. Note that
$|\Omega|=3^{75}$.

The probability $p_1$ that the groups are balanced is

$$
p_1=\frac{\binom{75}{25}\times\binom{75-25}{25}}{3^{75}}=\frac{27356996443592349250523576343392}{2503155504993241601315571986085849} \approx 0.01
$$

If we put $S_1=Marc$ and $S_2=Gato$, the probability $p_2$ that Marc and Gato belong to the same group is the probability that $f(2)=f(1)$ for $f\in \Omega$, i.e. $\frac{3}{9}=\frac{1}{3}$.

Comment: I think is $3^{75}$ right? Your answer is clear thanks. Just one remark with your answer, we choose an $\Omega$ to have equiprobability? In my course in any case we tried to choose an $\Omega$ to have this equiprobability (because computing probability it's much easier then). Also do you know how can I compute *my* $\omega$? (+1)

Comment: @MarcGato Corrected my $3^{75}$, thanks. It seems that your $\Omega$ only counts the size of the groups and forgets who’s in what group, so it does not make sense to ask "the probability that Marc and Gato belong to the same group" in your $\Omega$.

Comment: In fact I don't understand how did you compute the probability that $f(2)=f(1)$? It's not $2/9$?

Comment: @MarcGato To compute the probability that $f(2)=f(1)$, put $a=f(1),b=f(2)$. Then $(a,b) \in \lbrace 1,2,3 \rbrace^2$ : this makes $3\times3=9$ values. Now, $f(2)=f(1)$ means that $a=b$, which gives the values $(k,k);1\leq k\leq 3$ : this makes $3$ values. Eventually the probability is $\frac{3}{9}=\frac{1}{3}$

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 possible groups, and 75 people in total, so the total possibilities are: $3^{75}.$

If we choose a group for Marc and Gato, we can do so in 3 ways. Now, we have a group with only 2 people in it, so to fill the rest of the group, we chose 23 people from the 72 remaining. To make the second group, we choose 25 from the leftover 50.

So I believe the probability is something like:$$\frac{3\cdot\binom{73}{23}\binom{50}{25}}{3^{75}}$$

However, I'm not sure whether we'll need to divide by a factor of 2 or not as the remaining two groups may be indistinguishable.

Comment: Thanks but $3^{75}$ is not the probability..

Comment: @MarcGato I'm fairly certain I didn't say it was.