# Compute Card$(\{(m_1,m_2,m_3)\in\{0,\dots,75\}^3: m_1+m_2+m_3=75\})$.

Tags: combinatorics

This question arose from [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/946792/75-students-in-three-balanced-groups-probability-cardinality). Now I just want to know how can I compute the cardinal of $$\{(m_1,m_2,m_3)\in\{0,\dots,75\}^3: m_1+m_2+m_3=75\}$$ (curiosity).

Any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean by *cardinal*? The size of the set?

Comment: @barakmanos yes..

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_%28combinatorics%29

Comment: @barakmanos Thank you for this linK.

Comment: You're welcome :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's the number of [weak compositions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_(combinatorics)) of $n=75$ with $k=3$ parts. General solution is $\binom{n+k-1}{k-1}$, which is $2926$ in your case, I think.

Comment: What an interesting thing, I've found this formula in last year, after sitting on it all night :D. I've tried to avoid using binomial distribution in my home task) My attempt was successful (I've checked my answer with monte-carlo), but my teacher didn't understood what I've meant and said that I've failed. I found my writings! Take a look (1.82 MB) http://i.imgbox.com/0W2COHic.jpg It's just funny now)

Answer (score 0):

If you choose $m_1,m_2 \in \{0,...,75\}$ with $m_1 + m_2 \leq 75$ you are just fixing $m_3$. For each fixed choice of $m_1$ you have $m_2 \in \{0,...,75-m_2\}$. So the cardinal of our set is $\sum_{m_1=0}^{75}(76-m_1)$.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine as if you had $3$ numbered boxes, and $75$ identical (not distinguishable) marble you want to distribute in them. Then the number of ways you can distribute them corresponds to the cardinality you seek. Imagine it with $3$ boxes and 6 marbles. For instance:

$$[XX] \, [XXX] \, [X]$$

This can also be represented this way:

$$XX|XXX|X \,\, (*)$$

And the number of permutations of permutations of $(*)$ is your answer. Which is the permutations of the number of total symbols of $(*)$ (in your case $77$ symbols), so $77!$, divided by the sub-permutations of $X$'s, which is $75!$ and of the lines $2!$ for you is $\frac{77!}{2!(75)!}=\binom{77}{2}$.

In general, for $n$ marbles and $k$ boxes we'd get, if you follow the same procedure: $\binom{n+k-1}{k-1}$. As you see, in your case, $n = 75,k=3 \Rightarrow \binom{n+k-1}{k-1} = \binom{77}{2}$.